# Post Processing LTTNG (CTF) Trace Data

Tags: lttng

I've created tracepoints that capture some raw data.  I want to be able to post-process this data and possibly create a new viewer for the tracing perspective in Eclipse but I really have no idea where to start.  I was hoping to find a document that described how to create a new viewer for the trace eclipse perspective, how to read the ctf files, and how to graph the results in the view.

Alternatively, I'd just like to read the trace data and add some new trace events with postprocessed data.

As background to the question, I want to perform analysis on the trace timestamps and generate statistics about the average throughput and latency.  Although I can do this while inserting the tracepoint, I'd like to offload the math to the analysis portion.

Rich

Answer (score 2):

In general, such analysis is better done in post-processing. Doing it at runtime in your traced program may affect performance, to a point where the data you collect is not representative of the real behaviour of the application anymore!

The [Trace Compass documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Trace_Compass#User_Guides), particularly [this section](http://archive.eclipse.org/tracecompass/doc/org.eclipse.tracecompass.doc.dev/View-Tutorial.html#View_Tutorial), explains how to create new graphical views in Eclipse.

If you want to output a time-graph or XY-chart view, you can also look at the data-driven XML interface. It is more limited in features, but can work straight off the RCP (no need to recompile, no need to setup the dev environmnent).

Comment: As I don't have enough karma yet to post more than 2 links at a time ;) the XML interface is documented [here](http://archive.eclipse.org/tracecompass/doc/org.eclipse.tracecompass.doc.user/Data-driven-analysis.html#Data_driven_analysis), with a full example/tutorial [here](https://github.com/alexmonthy/ust-tc-example).